# HITS algorithm for bidirectional edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, ranking

As far as I know, the HITS (Hyperlink-Induced Topic Search) algorithm is used on directed graphs to calculate the hub and authority scores of the vertices.

However, if the edge is bidirectional (meaning a page has an out-link to the page that has in in-link to it), how does this affect the computation of the scores?

Comment: A further question here is, how will the hub and authority scores be for a cyclic graph with k nodes?